# codeigniter: trying to remove "&" sign from image name, but not happening, bcoz of that getimagesize() giving error

Tags: php, codeigniter

**codeigniter: trying to remove "&" sign from image name, but not happening, bcoz of that getimagesize() giving error**

I am working on image uploading, but getting issue when image contains "&" symbol in image name.

I am trying to remove that symbole from image name but not happening.

Tried With Following Statements:

```
$filename = str_replace(" ","&",$_FILES["prod_images"]["name"][$i]);

$filename = str_replace(" ","&amp;",$_FILES["prod_images"]["name"][$i]);

$filename = str_replace(" ","&#38;",$_FILES["prod_images"]["name"][$i]);
```

But "&" symbol is not getting removed from image name.

please suggest me changes or statement.

Comment: Removing `&` symbol in name and `getimagesize() giving error "path/file does not exist"` is two different errors/states. As well as we cant see `getimagesize` in your code

Comment: @AbdullaNilam this issue only during "&" symbol in image name.. if we remove that from image name during up.. then it will be resolved

Comment: show us `getimagesize` and associated codes

Comment: I removed getimagesize() part from code.. just want to remove "&" sign from image name

Comment: Best  way to upload file is saving the file name in DB (check SQL injections), and upload file with temp file name with date timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$filename = preg_replace("/[&_' ]/","",$_FILES["prod_images"]["name"][$i]);
```

put all unwanted characters in square brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean($string) {
 $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

then

```
$filename = clean($_FILES["prod_images"]["name"][$i]);
```